# Is babel breaking my labels?

Tags: cross-referencing, babel

I'm wondering if the `babel` package is breaking my labels. I'm calling `babel` with this:

```
% Russian
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\addto{\captionsrussian}{%
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}
}
```

and declaring my labels like this:

```
\begin{table}[h] \label{tab:declensionofsamyi}
```

and calling my labels like this:

```
The full declension of \fbox{\textbf{самый}} is provided in \ref{tab:declensionofsamyi}.
```

which outputs the following:

```
The full declension of самый is provided in Table .
```

As you can see, there isn't a number displayed when I reference a label. It is like this whenever I want to reference a label. However, captions in my `table`s display numbers correctly.

If I'm doing something wrong or this is a trivial fix, please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This not the result of `babel`. You need to put the `\caption` of your `table` before using `\label`, otherwise the referencing is incorrect. The command `\caption` increases the `table` counter **plus** adding a reference point in your document. This is typically done by the single `\refstepcounter{table}` command. So, your `table` structure has to look like this:

```
...
\begin{table}[..]
  % <stuff before caption>
  \caption[<ToC entry>]{<normal entry>}
  \label{<table label>}
  % <stuff after caption>
\end{table}
...
```

Comment: This seems to have been the issue. All references now act normally, per your suggestion. Thank you for your response!